# How to protect file from deletion using nsis?

Tags: filesystems, installation, nsis

I want to lock a file to prevent it from deletion during installation process, but I need to read this file at the same time. How can I do it using NSIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileOpen $0 "$instdir\myfile.txt" r` should block the deletion and allow you to read from it...

Comment: Don't forget `FileClose` after use.

Comment: @Seki: Keeping the handle open was sort of the point, Windows will close the handle for you when the process ends...

Comment: Yes, I understand the trick to keep the file open, and I know that windows will do the tidy for us at the end. But I keep as good pratice to close myself the files that I open, like I always write the line with `free()` when I `malloc()` :)